# Remove <?xml /> tags and their content

Tags: php, regex

I have in PHP a string which contain stuff like this:

```
<div>some html</div>
<?xml:namespace prefix = st1 ns = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:smarttags" />
<div>more html</div>
```

I need to remove all occurences of xml tags and everything they contain. I think one might use regex to do that but I don't how to use it.

Comment: Parse it using a regular XML-parser and remove every processing-instruction (thats what every `<?xyz ?>` is)

Comment: @Ghazanfar Mir That will strip all the tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use strip_tags if you want remove all markup or this

```
$string =' <tag> asdasd <tag>asdasd</tag> <?xml:namespace prefix = st1 ns = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:smarttags" /> text';

echo preg_replace('/<\?xml[^>]+\/>/im', '', $string);
```

Comment: preg_replace seems to work, thanks. I want to preserve the <div> + other html tags so can't use strip_tags.

Answer (score 1):

This will fail in some cases, but it will work for your supplied string:

```
$string = '
    <div>some html</div>
    <?xml:namespace prefix = st1 ns = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:smarttags" />
    <div>more html</div>
';
preg_replace('/<\?xml.*?\/>/im', '', $string);
```

Comment: That `.*` is greedy, so if there are two `<? ... />` tags, it'll gobble them both up as well as everything in between.

Comment: @CharlieSomerville, yup, as I said it would fail in some cases

Comment: Right, so try changing it to `.*?` to make it un-greedy

Comment: As CharlieSomerville, `.*` is greedy, I have now changed it to what I *think* is non greedy.